# woocommerce message "has been added to your card" corrupted

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

on my website the message: product "has been added to your basket" appears with some fragments of code. It looks like that

has been added to your basket.

```
jQuery('.woocommerce-message a').remove(); 
jQuery('.mini-cart').addClass('active cart-active'); 
jQuery('#main-content').click(function(){ jQuery('.mini-cart').removeClass('active cart-active');}); 
jQuery('.mini-cart').hover(function(){jQuery('.cart-active').removeClass('cart-active');});
setTimeout(function(){jQuery('.cart-active').removeClass('active')}, 6000);
```

Would be grateful for any suggestion what to do. I didn't do anything with any php file.

Comment: Please include link to website, but it appears as though you don't have a beginning <script> tag in front of jQuery('.woocommerce-message a')

Comment: Hi @Demodave, here is the link [link](https://www.definiteglam.co.uk)

Comment: Solved by unchecking "show cart dropdown when product is added to cart" in Appearence->Theme Options->Product Page. However, I do not know what was wrong with it.